# Retrofit onFailure not working in login method

Tags: php, android, laravel, api, retrofit

I'm calling a login method from Laravel using Retrofit , my problem is that when writing right username and password , it opens the other activity and everything's fine, but when writing wrong infos it doesn't open anything but doesn't show the message error either. What is missing?

Laravel code:

```
    public function login(Request $request) {

    $assistant = DB::table('assistants')
        ->where('username', $request->input('username'))
        ->where('mot_de_passe', $request->input('mot_de_passe'))
        ->first();


    if($assistant != null){

        return response()->json ($assistant);
    }else{
        $returnData = array(
            'status' => 'false',
            'message' => 'write some message..');
        return response()->json ($returnData ,500  );
    }}
```

Retrofit:

```
      IAssistant iAssistant= APIClient.getClient().create(IAssistant.class);


              iAssistant.login(username.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString()).enqueue(new Callback<Assistant>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<Assistant> call, Response<Assistant> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BottomNavigation.class));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"assistant"+response.body().getNom(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 }}

                @Override
                public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<Assistant> call, Throwable t) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"'error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.v("tag!!!!!!!!!!","error"+t.getMessage());

                }
                });
```

Comment: But you got a response. Just it is not successful. Try to add an `else` to your `if` statement in `onResponse` and see what happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seen from the [official javadoc](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/).

`onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t)`

> Invoked when a network exception occurred talking to the server or when an unexpected exception occurred creating the request or processing the response.

`onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response)`

> Invoked for a received HTTP response.

In the code you paste, it seems you're getting an HTTP response.

Ok, it is a 500's code response, so not a good one, but anyway.

This is why there is a `isSuccessful()` method in the `Response` as it is explained in the *Method details*

*`onResponse()` Method details from the doc*

> Note: An HTTP response may still indicate an application-level failure such as a 404 or 500. Call Response.isSuccessful() to determine if the response indicates success.

So for you to handle it, update your code in this way

```
public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<Assistant> call, Response<Assistant> response) {
    if (response.isSuccessful()){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BottomNavigation.class));
    } else {
     // Handle your 500 here
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! stupid mistake, it worked, thanks! but can you explain me why you said its not a good one about the 500's code response?

Comment: I meant not a *good* one as not a *2XX-3XX* ! You received this response, ok it is not a *good* (like a successful one), but it is a response anyway, that is why it does go on `onResponse` and not `onFailure` :)